# PUTTY inputting random combinations of text when highlighting

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm trying to highlight some text in PUTTY but when I try to highlight, it detects it as a keyboard input.
Even when using the scroll wheel https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/axlnwkkicfk2ezn/Exp5oxEmE3.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ran a program which enabled "mouse reporting" mode in the terminal (e.g. Vim or some other text editor) – and then the program crashed without a chance to disable this mode.

The terminal (PuTTY) is completely unaware of what programs are running on the other end, so it cannot automatically disable such modes when a program exits (it doesn't know when a program exits).

Such modes are enabled and disabled by printing out special control sequences, so try running

```
printf '\e[?%dl' 9 {1000..1007} 1015
```

to clear the stuck state. Or actually just use the `reset` command which should fix everything.

You can also temporarily bypass the "mouse reporting" mode (when it's working properly) by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while selecting text.